# Сервисы Google Play - работает на AVD, не работает на устройстве

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

В чем вопрос - в приложении подключены сервисы google play для рейтинга игроков и ачивок, на виртуальном устройстве в AVD все отлично работает включая вход и выход из сервисов. Приложение в маркете еще не опубликовано. Есть версии для внутреннего теста и для альфа теста, группы тестеров добавлены, почтовый аккаунт добавлен в список тестеров, приложение проверено и в качестве билда из студии и в качестве подписанного из альфа раздела консоли - сервисы не функционируют.

Кратко: в AVD работает все, на физическом девайсе не входит в сервисы - появляется окно с выбором аккаунта, после выбора оно закрывается и все

Comment: День добрый. Логи покажите что ли =/

Comment: если бы знал как, показал бы) можно чуть подробнее где их взять из устройства и все пришлю

Comment: Вы же в Android Studio пишите? Подключите и смотрите в Logcat.

Comment: проблема на устройстве, в студии все в порядке

Comment: туплю. сейчас подключу телефон к студии

Comment: @Suvitruf так, все ок. Можно тогда вопрос? Судя по всему во всем виновато то, что я дико затроил. Если все ок при прямом подключении тела к студии, но ничего не работает при билде апк и прямой установке и запуске с устройства - это нормально? После публикации приложения в маркете все будет работать у пользователей?

Comment: А вы каким ключом подписываете .apk?

Comment: сгенерировал ключ во время создания апк через build -> generate signed bundle/apk

Comment: А в Google Play вы зиливали первый раз подписывали им же или debug ключом?

Comment: первый залив в плей был подписан этим ключом, тип версии был выбран release

Comment: версия после билда установленная из тела к сервисам не подклчюается, версия, которая сама установилась во время теста тела через студию работает и подключается к сервисам

Comment: Явно выглядит как проблема с ключом. Включите полные логи, соберите apk, подключите телефон и скопируйте в вопрос логи из Студии.

Comment: Попробовал сделать новый билд с другим ключом - приложение из памяти устройства вообще не устанавливается, со старым ключом тоже через раз. можно с вами как-то связаться через скайп или вк чтобы здесь не спамить? У меня не достаточно рейтинга чтобы начать с вами чат.

Answer (score 0):

После первой генерации приложения нужно обновить SHA-1 в настройках Oauth, нужный ключ и код ошибки показывается в logcat во время запуска ошибочного прложения